# JQuery dialogs' modal and position attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to have a form field by users on my web application to be a jquery popup window. I have the following code:

```
$(".form").dialog({
    modal: true;    
})
```

I'm not getting the desired result; the rest of the document(webpage) hidden or rather deactivated by the form. I want to have the user's focus to be on the form until the user clicks a button on the dialog.

I would also like to position the form in the centre of the page. I will appreciate any help with resolving the problems.

Comment: Have you included jQuery in your code?

Comment: Can you show us the html code ?

Comment: Find out the errors in ur `Inspect Element`.

Comment: If you mean the JQuery library, I have added it.

Comment: Where do I paste the code so you can see? The comment text field is limited on the characters that can be typed.

Comment: @user3035404: jsfiddle.net

Comment: You need jQuery UI as well as jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Remove ";" from your expression.

This may be correct:

```
$(function() {
    $(".form" ).dialog({
        modal: true
    });    
  });
```

This examle you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/JN7pL/

P.S. Sorry for my English

Answer (score 0):

In general this code should work, I've tested it here: http://jsfiddle.net/6YKmh/

Few things to check:

1) make you have necessary jQuery libs loaded, so in your "head" you have something like:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
```

2) make sure your match $(".form") actually matches something in your html i.e. you have an element with class="form" attribute like this:

```
<form class="form">
  <fieldset>
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

3) make sure your js call

```
$(".form").dialog({
modal: true    
})
```

in html is either declared below the element you match with  $(".form") , or wrap it in $(document).ready(function(){..}) :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".form").dialog({
    modal: true    
  })    
});
```

Comment: Vasily pinpointed the semicolon problem that I missed, so I'd vote for his answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21332398/2606131

Comment: Thank you very much for your contributions. Its now able to hide the parent webpage. I included jquery-ui.css file. But the position attribute is not yet positioning my form in the centre.